# 'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file - Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven, release, gnupg

I just got my free Sonatype Maven repo and have been attempting to do a release. However whilst trying to do this I get an error when maven-gpg-plugin attempts to sign artifacts.

I get a ton of asterisks showing beforehand and I just press enter and then I get this issue, here's my full log: http://pastebin.com/GkLbFgBF

Here are the command line parameters I am attempting to use
    clean install javadoc:javadoc javadoc:jar source:jar release:clean release:prepare release:perform

I installed gpg4win thinking that might solve this but it hasn't.

Comment: How about running `gpg` from the command-line?  Does that work?  `gpg.exe` is not in the PATH - that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As each system is differently configured the following steps works in some cases.

when you receive this error message, “gpg is not recognized as an internal or external command” then you need to update your PATH variable.

To do this without reboot:

1. Open up a command prompt window
2. Paste this in:

   ```
   SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG
   ```
3. Hit Enter

Comment: Thanks :) managed to figure this out awhile back but forgot to update this question (sorry). But others may benefit from this!

Comment: Doesn't have to be exactly that PATH but rather where `gpg.exe` is located. For instance in my case it was C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy fix (at least for me) was to just copy the `gnupg` using the File Explorer interface from whatever folder it got saved to when you originally downloaded it. Then make sure it's pasted into both `Program Files (x86)` and `Program Files` folders in `c:` or `Windows(c:)`

I was getting the `gpg is not recognized as an internal or external command` error during a Linux Mint authentication check.  Checked the `PATH` saw that `C:\*AnyDirectory*\gnupg\bin` was absent. Went to my `c:` folder in File Explorer and searched `gnupg` saw that it was in `Program Files` but not in `Program Files (x86)` fixed that now I get `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnupg\bin` in my `PATH` and the error message went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another plugin https://www.simplify4u.org/sign-maven-plugin/ for signing artifacts.

`sign-maven-plugin` does not use `gpg` for signing, it use java `BouncyCastle` for signing artifacts so you need not install `gpg` executable and plugin works on any operating system without special configuration.